# Difference between calling a function normally vs callign it through exports object?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I've been learning how to unit test javascript code with **jest** and I was trying to mock some function that's being called inside another function, like this:

```
//Module.js
function b(){
  return 'b';
}

function a(){
  return b();
}

export {a ,b};
```

Simply put, i wanted to test **function a** by mocking **function b** for unit testing purposes.

This is what I tried to do to test **function a**

```
//Module.test.js
import * as module from 'Module.js'

test('a', () => {
  jest.spyOn(module, 'b').mockReturnValue('c');  
  expect(module.a()).toBe('c');
})
```

But the **return value** that was being returned was still that of the original implementation of **function b** (`'b'`) instead of the mock value `'c'`  that I was expecting it to be

The solution that I found on a blog post suggested that in order for my test to use the mocked version of **function b**, I needed to add `exports.` to the function call inside **function a** in `Modules.js` like so:

```
//Module.js
function b(){
  return 'b';
}

function a(){
  return exports.b(); //suggested changes here
}

export {a ,b};
```

and it did work .... but It didn't really explain why it does work....

Basically, I'm trying to understand what the difference between calling a function by its name vs calling a function through an **exports** object is.

Comment: In the original code, it's getting `b` through the local scope of the module, not through the object that's exported. But Jest is modifying the exported object, not the original function.

Comment: @Barmar  I see, one more quesstion though...  should I expect the application to run normally even if this function a is calling function b through the exports object?

Comment: Normally there shouldn't be any difference. It's only when you're redefining functions dynamically that there can be issues. That's what's going on when you mock the function in Jest.

Comment: If you are using ES6 `export` syntax, there is no `exports` object on which `.b()` could be called on - unless you are transpiling back to commonjs

Comment: @Bergi whats the quickest way to know if the code is being transpiled to cjs?

Comment: IIRC jest does it by default, but look at its configuration. You can also fire up a debugger (but look out for source maps) and/or print the `__filename` - no wait actually [jest messes with that as well](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10568)… But actually my comment was in reference to the production build not the jest testing, so just check how you are calling `node` in production.